# ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row in oracle sql

Tags: oracle

```
--ACCOUNT LEVEL
WITH dim_date
    --- IF FILTER IS CURRENT MONTH AND NOT COMPLETE THE WHOLE MONT, REPORT WILL SHOW A PREVIOUS MONTH DATA INSTEAD.
AS (
    SELECT --- CURRENT MONTH
        SYSDATE AS TODAY
        ,NEXT_DAY((TO_DATE(:AS_DATE,'MM-dd-yyyy')-7),'MONDAY') AS FOW
        ,NEXT_DAY((TO_DATE(:AS_DATE,'MM-dd-yyyy')),'SUNDAY ') AS EOW
        FROM DUAL
    )
    -- CUSTOMER DETIAL FROM 
    ,customer
AS (
    SELECT sttm_customer.customer_no
        ,short_name AS customer_name
        ,NATIONALITY
        ,CASE 
            WHEN UNIQUE_ID_NAME = 'ID-CARD'
                THEN 'N'
            WHEN UNIQUE_ID_NAME = 'PASSPORT'
                THEN 'P'
            END AS ID_TYPE
        ,UNIQUE_ID_VALUE AS ID_NUMBER
        ,COUNTRY AS COUNTRY_CODE
        ,LOCAL_BRANCH AS BRANCH
        ,FULL_NAME
        ,SEX
        ,RESIDENT_STATUS
        ,to_char(DOB,'DDMMYYYY') as DATE_OF_BIRTH
        ,D_ADDRESS1 || D_ADDRESS2 || D_ADDRESS3 || D_ADDRESS4 AS ADDRESS
        
        ,MARITAL_STATUS
        ,CASE 
            WHEN EMPLOYMENT_STATUS in ('T' , 'P','F') 
                THEN 'N'
            WHEN EMPLOYMENT_STATUS = 'S' 
                THEN 'Y'
            WHEN EMPLOYMENT_STATUS in ('U','R','N','O') 
                THEN 'O'
            END EMPLOYMENT_STATUS
        --,EMPLOYMENT_STATUS
        ,DESIGNATION AS BUSINESS_TYPE
        ,SALARY
        ,CCY_PERS_INCEXP AS SALARY_CURRENCY
        ,USER_NAME AS RM_NAME
        ,GROUP_ID
        ,CCR_CIF
        ,SI
        ,WACTHLIST
        ,CREDIT_LAST_APPROVAL_DATE
        ,CREDIT_NEXT_REVIEW_DATE
        ,PEP_PERSON
        ,CIF_PACKAGE_DESC
        ,INCOME_SOURCE_SECTOR
        ,'' AS COLLATERAL_VALUE
        ,CASE WHEN NVL(RP1.RELATED_PARTIES,'') <> '' and NVL(RP2.RELATED_PARTIES,'') <> ''
            THEN '02' --IF both not null, show yes/no 
            ELSE NVL(RP1.RELATED_PARTIES,RP2.RELATED_PARTIES) 
         END RELATED_PARTIES 
         ,ID.ID_SERIES 
    FROM sttm_customer
    LEFT JOIN (
        select sv1.CUSTOMER_NUMBER
            , sv1.person_id
            , DECODE(sv2.ID_SERIES,'any','ANY',sv2.ID_SERIES) ID_SERIES
        from sv_CM_CUSTOMERS sv1
        join sv_cm_identity_card sv2 on sv1.person_id = sv2.person_id
        ) ID
        ON ID.CUSTOMER_NUMBER = sttm_customer.customer_no
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT customer_no
            ,SEX
            ,RESIDENT_STATUS
            ,DATE_OF_BIRTH AS DOB
            ,D_ADDRESS1
            ,D_ADDRESS2
            ,D_ADDRESS3
            ,D_ADDRESS4
        FROM STTM_CUST_PERSONAL
        ) personal
        ON personal.customer_no = sttm_customer.customer_no
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT customer_no
            ,EMPLOYMENT_STATUS
            ,DESIGNATION
            ,SALARY
            ,CCY_PERS_INCEXP
        FROM STTMS_CUST_PROFESSIONAL
        ) professional
        ON professional.customer_no = sttm_customer.customer_no
    LEFT JOIN STTMS_CUST_DOMESTIC
        ON STTMS_CUST_DOMESTIC.customer_no = sttm_customer.customer_no
    /* RM USER :- Relationship Manager*/
    LEFT JOIN SMTB_USER U
        ON U.USER_ID = STTM_CUSTOMER.RM_ID
    /* CUSTOMER'S GROUP ID*/
    LEFT JOIN STTMS_CUST_GROUP GRP
        ON GRP.CUSTOMER_NO = STTM_CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_NO
    /*CCR_CIF*/
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT rtrim(REC_KEY, '~') AS REC_KEY
            ,FIELD_VAL_17 AS CCR_CIF
        FROM cstm_function_userdef_fields
        ) CCR_CIF
        ON CCR_CIF.REC_KEY = STTM_CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_NO
    /*si*/
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT rtrim(REC_KEY, '~') AS REC_KEY
            ,FIELD_VAL_18 AS SI
        FROM cstm_function_userdef_fields
        ) SI
        ON SI.REC_KEY = STTM_CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_NO
    /*WATCHLIST*/
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT rtrim(REC_KEY, '~') AS REC_KEY
            ,FIELD_VAL_23 AS WACTHLIST
        FROM cstm_function_userdef_fields
        ) WATCHLIST
        ON WATCHLIST.REC_KEY = STTM_CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_NO
    /*CREDIT_LAST_APPROVAL_DATE*/
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT rtrim(REC_KEY, '~') AS REC_KEY
            ,FIELD_VAL_37 AS CREDIT_LAST_APPROVAL_DATE
        FROM cstm_function_userdef_fields
        ) CREDIT_LAST_APPROVAL_DATE
        ON CREDIT_LAST_APPROVAL_DATE.REC_KEY = STTM_CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_NO
    /*CREDIT_NEXT_REVIEW_DATE*/
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT rtrim(REC_KEY, '~') AS REC_KEY
            ,FIELD_VAL_38 AS CREDIT_NEXT_REVIEW_DATE
        FROM cstm_function_userdef_fields
        ) CREDIT_NEXT_REVIEW_DATE
        ON CREDIT_NEXT_REVIEW_DATE.REC_KEY = STTM_CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_NO
    /*PEP PERSON*/
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT rtrim(REC_KEY, '~') AS REC_KEY
            ,FIELD_VAL_22 AS PEP_PERSON
        FROM cstm_function_userdef_fields
        ) PEP
        ON PEP.REC_KEY = STTM_CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_NO
    /*CIF PACKAGE DESC*/
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT rtrim(REC_KEY, '~') AS REC_KEY
            ,LOV_DESC AS CIF_PACKAGE_DESC
        FROM cstm_function_userdef_fields t1
        join UDTM_LOV on t1.FIELD_VAL_10 = UDTM_LOV.LOV and UDTM_LOV.field_name = 'PACKAGE'
        WHERE function_id ='STDCIF'
        ) CIF_PACKAGE_DESC
        ON CIF_PACKAGE_DESC.REC_KEY = STTM_CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_NO
    /*INCOME SOURCE SECTOR*/
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT rtrim(REC_KEY, '~') AS REC_KEY
            ,field_val_15 AS INCOME_SOURCE_SECTOR
        FROM cstm_function_userdef_fields
        WHERE function_id = 'STDCIF'
        ) ISS
        ON ISS.REC_KEY = STTM_CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_NO
    -- Yes or No related parties
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT DISTINCT customer_id
            ,field_char_12 AS related_parties
        FROM cltb_account_master
        WHERE field_char_12 = '01_Yes' --IS NOT NULL
        ) RP1
        ON rp1.customer_id = STTM_CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_NO
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT DISTINCT customer_id
            ,field_char_12 AS related_parties
        FROM cltb_account_master
        WHERE field_char_12 = '01_No' --IS NOT NULL
        ) RP2
        ON rp2.customer_id = STTM_CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_NO
    )
    -- CARD AND CARD ACCOUNT FROM SV FILE 
    ,card
AS (
    SELECT card_acc.card_id
        ,card_acc.account_number
        ,card.CARD_NUMBER
        ,card.CUSTOMER_NUMBER
        ,cardc.start_date AS START_DATE
        ,cardc.end_date AS END_DATE
        ,card_instance.expiration_date AS CARD_EXPIRY_DATE
        ,CARD_ACC.CURRENCY AS CREDIT_ACCOUNT_CURRENCY
    FROM SV_CD_ACCOUNT card_acc -- GET ACCOUNT 
    LEFT JOIN SV_CD_CARDS card -- GET CARD OPENED UNDER ACCOUNT 
        ON card.card_id = CARD_ACC.CARD_ID
    LEFT JOIN SV_CM_CONTRACT cardc -- CARD START DATE 
        ON cardc.customer_id = card.customer_id
            AND cardc.CONTRACT_ID = card.CONTRACT_ID
    -- CARD INSTANCE IS A TABLE CONTAINING CARD HISTORY EX.SUSPEND, RENEW CARD SO NEED TO GET ONLY THE UPDATED ONE
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT card_id
            ,expiration_date
        FROM (
            SELECT card_id
                ,expiration_date
                ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                    PARTITION BY CARD_ID ORDER BY DT DESC
                    ) AS MAX_SEQ -- row number to get only the latest record of card
            FROM SV_CD_CARD_INSTANCE
            )
        WHERE MAX_SEQ = 1 -- get the last record of card    
        ) card_instance
        ON card_instance.card_id = card.card_id
    CROSS JOIN DIM_DATE
    WHERE 0=0 --ACCOUNT_STATUS <> 'ACSTCLSD' -- active account
        AND SUBSTR(CARD_NUMBER, 1, 6) IN (
            '449925'
            ,'436490'
            ) -- GET ONLY BBC CREDIT CARD
        AND cardc.start_date between NEXT_DAY((TO_DATE(:AS_DATE,'MM-dd-yyyy')-7),'MONDAY') and NEXT_DAY((TO_DATE(:AS_DATE,'MM-dd-yyyy')),'SUNDAY ')
    )
    -- ACCOUNTING DETAIL BY CARD 
    ,card_fcc
AS (
    SELECT sv_card_account
        --      ,SV_CARD_ID
        -- convert row to column
        ,sum(CASE 
                WHEN ac_no = 91500001
                    THEN CASE WHEN PRODUCT_CODE in ('EC45', 'EC46', 'EC47', 'ECC4', 'EC44','EC85', 'EC86', 'EC87', 'ECC5', 'ECC84')
                        THEN lcy_amount
                        ELSE 0
                        END
                ELSE 0
                END) AS CARD_LIMIT_AMOUNT
        ,sum(CASE 
                WHEN ac_no = 91500001
                    THEN lcy_amount
                ELSE 0
                END) AS AVL_LIMIT_BAL --CARD_LIMIT_AMOUNT
        ,sum(CASE 
                WHEN ac_no = 13321000
                    THEN lcy_amount
                ELSE 0
                END) AS FCY_BALANCE
        ,sum(CASE 
                WHEN ac_no = 13321000
                    THEN lcy_amount
                ELSE 0
                END) AS LCY_BALANCE
        ,sum(CASE 
                WHEN ac_no = 25321000
                    THEN lcy_amount
                ELSE 0
                END) AS ACCRUED_INTEREST
        ,sum(CASE 
                WHEN ac_no = 13321000
                    THEN CASE WHEN PRODUCT_CODE in ('EC54', 'EC55')
                        THEN lcy_amount
                        ELSE 0
                        END
                ELSE 0
                END) AS TOTAL_PENALTY_AMOUNT
    -- CONVERT COLUMN FROM ORIGINAL TABLE
    FROM (
        SELECT CASE 
                WHEN DRCR_IND = 'D'
                    THEN (LCY_AMOUNT) * - 1
                ELSE abs(LCY_AMOUNT)
                END AS LCY_AMOUNT
            ,ac_no
            ,trn_dt
            ,substr(trn_ref_no, 4, 4) as PRODUCT_CODE
            ,(
                SELECT DISTINCT iss_account_number AS sv_card_account
                FROM (
                    SELECT DISTINCT a.trn_ref_no
                        ,b.iss_account_number
                    FROM iftb_fileupd_xmlcr_trn_custom a
                    JOIN iftb_fileupd_xmlcr_custom b
                        ON a.oper_id = b.oper_id
                            AND a.seq_number = b.seq_number
                    ) c
                WHERE c.TRN_REF_NO = a.TRN_REF_NO
                ) AS sv_card_account
            ,(
                SELECT DISTINCT iss_card_id AS sv_card_id
                FROM (
                    SELECT DISTINCT a.trn_ref_no
                        ,b.iss_card_id
                    FROM iftb_fileupd_xmlcr_trn_custom a
                    JOIN iftb_fileupd_xmlcr_custom b
                        ON a.oper_id = b.oper_id
                            AND a.seq_number = b.seq_number
                    ) c
                WHERE c.TRN_REF_NO = a.TRN_REF_NO
                ) AS sv_card_id
        FROM acvw_all_ac_entries a
        CROSS JOIN dim_date
        WHERE ac_no IN (
                91500001
                ,13321000
                ,25321000
                ) -- LCY AMOUNT, FCY AMOUNT. OVER LIMIT CREDIT
            AND TRN_DT between NEXT_DAY((TO_DATE(:AS_DATE,'MM-dd-yyyy')-7),'MONDAY') and NEXT_DAY((TO_DATE(:AS_DATE,'MM-dd-yyyy')),'SUNDAY ')
        ) ac_entries
    LEFT JOIN (select distinct(account_number) account_number
                    ,min(start_date) start_date
        FROM card
        group by account_number) CARD
        ON card.account_number = ac_entries.sv_card_account
            --AND card.card_id = ac_entries.sv_card_id
    CROSS JOIN dim_date
    WHERE trn_dt between NEXT_DAY((TO_DATE(:AS_DATE,'MM-dd-yyyy')-7),'MONDAY') and NEXT_DAY((TO_DATE(:AS_DATE,'MM-dd-yyyy')),'SUNDAY ')
    GROUP BY sv_card_account
        --      ,sv_card_id
    )
    -- O GET LASY PAYMENT DEFINED BY PRODICT CODE
    ,CARD_ACCOUNT_LAST_PAYMENT
AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM (
        SELECT sv_card_account
            ,TO_CHAR(trn_dt, 'DDMMYYYY') AS last_payment_date
            ,lcy_amount AS last_amount_paid
            ,row_number() OVER (
                PARTITION BY sv_card_account ORDER BY trn_dt DESC
                ) AS rn
        FROM (
            SELECT  b.OPER_DATE trn_dt
                --,entry_seq_no
                ,(
                    CASE 
                        WHEN a.debit_credit_status = 'D'
                            THEN to_number(amount_value) * - 1
                        ELSE to_number(amount_value)
                        END
                    ) / RPAD(1, NVL((
                            SELECT CCY_DECIMALS
                            FROM CYTM_CCY_DEFN
                            WHERE ALT_CCY_CODE = A.AMT_CURRENCY
                            ), 0) + 1, 0) AS lcy_amount
                ,(
                    SELECT DISTINCT iss_account_number AS sv_card_account
                    FROM (
                        SELECT DISTINCT a.trn_ref_no
                            ,b.iss_account_number
                        FROM iftb_fileupd_xmlcr_trn_custom a
                        JOIN iftb_fileupd_xmlcr_custom b
                            ON a.oper_id = b.oper_id
                                AND a.seq_number = b.seq_number
                        ) c
                    WHERE c.TRN_REF_NO = a.TRN_REF_NO
                    ) AS sv_card_account
            FROM iftb_fileupd_xmlcr_trn_custom a
                JOIN iftb_fileupd_xmlcr_custom b
                    ON a.oper_id = b.oper_id
                        AND a.seq_number = b.seq_number
            CROSS JOIN DIM_DATE
            WHERE substr(trn_ref_no, 4, 4) IN (
                    'EC65'
                    ,'EC66'
                    ,'EC67'
                    ,'EC68'
                    ,'EC69'
                    ,'EC70'
                    ,'ECC6'
                    ,'ECC7'
                    ,'ECB7'
                    ,'ECB8'
                    ) -- PRODUCT CODE FOR PAYMENT
                AND b.OPER_DATE between NEXT_DAY((TO_DATE(:AS_DATE,'MM-dd-yyyy')-7),'MONDAY') and NEXT_DAY((TO_DATE(:AS_DATE,'MM-dd-yyyy')),'SUNDAY ')
            )
        )
    WHERE rn = 1
    )
    ,invoice
AS (
    SELECT card_number
        ,account_number
        , MIN_AMOUNT_DUE
        , GRACE_DATE
        ,total_amount_due AS TOTAL_PAYMENT_AMOUNT
        ,TO_CHAR(due_date, 'DDMMYYYY') AS PAYMENT_DUE_DATE
        ,TO_CHAR(add_months(due_date,1), 'DDMMYYYY') AS NEXT_DUE_DATE
        --,day_past_due AS OVERDUE_DAY
        ,CASE 
            WHEN AGING_PERIOD = 0
                THEN '0'
            WHEN AGING_PERIOD = 1
                THEN '0'
            WHEN AGING_PERIOD = 2
                THEN '15'
            WHEN AGING_PERIOD = 3
                THEN '31'
            WHEN AGING_PERIOD = 4
                THEN '61'
            WHEN AGING_PERIOD = 5
                THEN '91'
            ELSE ''
            END AS OVERDUE_DAY
        ,overdue_interest_balance + overdue_balance AS TOTAL_OVERDUE_AMOUNT
        /*,CASE 
            WHEN day_past_due BETWEEN 1
                    AND 29
                THEN '1'
            WHEN day_past_due BETWEEN 30
                    AND 59
                THEN '2'
            WHEN day_past_due BETWEEN 60
                    AND 89
                THEN '3'
            WHEN day_past_due BETWEEN 90
                    AND 119
                THEN '4'
            WHEN day_past_due BETWEEN 120
                    AND 149
                THEN '5'
            WHEN day_past_due BETWEEN 150
                    AND 179
                THEN '6'
            WHEN day_past_due BETWEEN 180
                    AND 209
                THEN '7'
            WHEN day_past_due BETWEEN 210
                    AND 239
                THEN '8'
            WHEN day_past_due BETWEEN 270
                    AND 269
                THEN '9'
            WHEN day_past_due BETWEEN 277
                    AND 299
                THEN 'T'
            WHEN day_past_due BETWEEN 300
                    AND 329
                THEN 'E'
            WHEN day_past_due BETWEEN 330
                    AND 359
                THEN 'Y'
            WHEN day_past_due >= 360
                AND day_past_due <= 361
                THEN 'L'
            WHEN day_past_due > 361 --'Write Off'
                THEN 'W'
            END AS PAYMENT_STATUS_CODE
        */
        , AGING_PERIOD AS PAYMENT_STATUS_CODE
        ,CASE 
            WHEN AGING_PERIOD = 0
                THEN 'Normal'
            WHEN AGING_PERIOD = 1
                THEN 'Normal'
            WHEN AGING_PERIOD = 2
                THEN 'Special'
            WHEN AGING_PERIOD = 3
                THEN 'Sub standard'
            WHEN AGING_PERIOD = 4
                THEN 'Doubtful'
            WHEN AGING_PERIOD = 5
                THEN 'Loss'
            ELSE TO_CHAR(AGING_PERIOD)
            END AS CLASSIFICATION
        ,INVOICE_DATE
    FROM SV_IN_INVOICE
    CROSS JOIN dim_Date
    WHERE INVOICE_DATE between NEXT_DAY((TO_DATE(:AS_DATE,'MM-dd-yyyy')-7),'MONDAY') and NEXT_DAY((TO_DATE(:AS_DATE,'MM-dd-yyyy')),'SUNDAY ')
    )
    , OVERLIMIT
AS (
    select trunc(O.oper_date,'MM') oper_date
        ,T.D_ACCOUNT_NUMBER
        , sum(DECODE(D_AMOUNT_VALUE,0,0, 
                    D_AMOUNT_VALUE / RPAD(1, NVL((SELECT CCY_DECIMALS
                                            FROM CYTM_CCY_DEFN
                                            WHERE ALT_CCY_CODE = T.D_AMT_CURRENCY
                                            ), 0) + 1, 0)
                    )
        ) amt 
    from SV_O_TRANSACTIONS T
        join sv_o_operations O
        on O.oper_id = T.oper_id 
        CROSS JOIN DIM_DATE
    where T.TRANSACTION_TYPE = 'TRNT1007'
            AND O.OPER_DATE between NEXT_DAY((TO_DATE(:AS_DATE,'MM-dd-yyyy')-7),'MONDAY') and NEXT_DAY((TO_DATE(:AS_DATE,'MM-dd-yyyy')),'SUNDAY ')
group by T.D_ACCOUNT_NUMBER,trunc(O.oper_date,'MM')
    )
    ,CARD_ACCOUNT_PERIOD_REPAYMENT
AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM (
        SELECT sv_card_account
            ,TO_CHAR(trn_dt, 'DDMMYYYY') AS last_payment_date
            ,lcy_amount AS last_amount_paid
            ,row_number() OVER (
                PARTITION BY sv_card_account ORDER BY trn_dt DESC
                ) AS rn
        FROM (
            SELECT  b.OPER_DATE trn_dt
                ,(
                    CASE 
                        WHEN a.debit_credit_status = 'D'
                            THEN to_number(amount_value) * - 1
                        ELSE to_number(amount_value)
                        END
                    ) / RPAD(1, NVL((
                            SELECT CCY_DECIMALS
                            FROM CYTM_CCY_DEFN
                            WHERE ALT_CCY_CODE = A.AMT_CURRENCY
                            ), 0) + 1, 0) AS lcy_amount
                ,(
                    SELECT DISTINCT iss_account_number AS sv_card_account
                    FROM (
                        SELECT DISTINCT a.trn_ref_no
                            ,b.iss_account_number
                        FROM iftb_fileupd_xmlcr_trn_custom a
                        JOIN iftb_fileupd_xmlcr_custom b
                            ON a.oper_id = b.oper_id
                                AND a.seq_number = b.seq_number
                        ) c
                    WHERE c.TRN_REF_NO = a.TRN_REF_NO
                    ) AS sv_card_account
            FROM iftb_fileupd_xmlcr_trn_custom a
                JOIN iftb_fileupd_xmlcr_custom b
                    ON a.oper_id = b.oper_id
                        AND a.seq_number = b.seq_number
                JOIN SV_IN_INVOICE INV
                    ON B.ISS_ACCOUNT_NUMBER = INV.ACCOUNT_NUMBER
            CROSS JOIN DIM_DATE
            WHERE substr(trn_ref_no, 4, 4) IN (
                    'EC65'
                    ,'EC66'
                    ,'EC67'
                    ,'EC68'
                    ,'EC69'
                    ,'EC70'
                    ,'ECC6'
                    ,'ECC7'
                    ,'ECB7'
                    ,'ECB8'
                    ) -- PRODUCT CODE FOR PAYMENT
                AND INVOICE_DATE between NEXT_DAY((TO_DATE(:AS_DATE,'MM-dd-yyyy')-7),'MONDAY') and NEXT_DAY((TO_DATE(:AS_DATE,'MM-dd-yyyy')),'SUNDAY ')
                AND (b.OPER_DATE > (select distinct (GRACE_DATE)+1-1/24/60/60 as grace_date from SV_IN_INVOICE where INVOICE_DATE = ADD_months(inv.INVOICE_DATE,-1))
                and b.OPER_DATE < INV.GRACE_DATE+1)
            )
        )
    WHERE rn = 1
    )
SELECT
    --RUNNING NUMBER
    row_number() OVER (
        ORDER BY card.account_number ASC
        ) AS no
    -- DIM CARD
    ,card.account_number
    ,CARD.CARD_NUMBER
    ,START_DATE
    ,END_DATE
    ,CARD_EXPIRY_DATE
    ,CREDIT_ACCOUNT_CURRENCY
    ,ACC.ACCOUNT_STATUS_DESC
    -- DIM CUSTOMER FROM FCC
    ,CUSTOMER.customer_no
    ,CUSTOMER.customer_name
    ,CUSTOMER.NATIONALITY
    ,CUSTOMER.ID_NUMBER
    ,CUSTOMER.ID_TYPE
    ,CUSTOMER.COUNTRY_CODE
    ,CUSTOMER.BRANCH
    ,CUSTOMER.FULL_NAME
    ,CUSTOMER.SEX
    ,CUSTOMER.RESIDENT_STATUS
    ,CUSTOMER.DATE_OF_BIRTH
    ,CUSTOMER.ADDRESS
    ,CUSTOMER.MARITAL_STATUS
    ,CUSTOMER.EMPLOYMENT_STATUS
    ,CUSTOMER.BUSINESS_TYPE
    ,CUSTOMER.SALARY
    ,CUSTOMER.SALARY_CURRENCY
    ,CUSTOMER.RM_NAME
    ,CUSTOMER.GROUP_ID
    ,CUSTOMER.CCR_CIF
    ,CUSTOMER.SI
    ,CUSTOMER.WACTHLIST
    ,CUSTOMER.CREDIT_LAST_APPROVAL_DATE
    ,CUSTOMER.CREDIT_NEXT_REVIEW_DATE
    ,CUSTOMER.PEP_PERSON
    ,CUSTOMER.CIF_PACKAGE_DESC
    ,CUSTOMER.INCOME_SOURCE_SECTOR
    ,CUSTOMER.ID_SERIES
    ,CUSTOMER.COLLATERAL_VALUE
    ,case when CUSTOMER.RELATED_PARTIES = '01_Yes' then 'Yes'
          when CUSTOMER.RELATED_PARTIES = '01_No' then 'No'
          when CUSTOMER.RELATED_PARTIES = '02' then 'Yes/No'
          else 'No'
    end as RELATED_PARTIES
    -- FIX VALUE
    ,'18%' AS INTEREST_RATE
    ,36 AS TENURE
    ,'Individuals' AS OWNERSHIP
    ,'055' AS INDUSTRY_CODE
    ,'RETAIL_Credit Cards' AS INDUSTRY_DESC
    ,'S' AS TERM_TYPE -- S = SHORT AND L= LONG
    -- FROM CARD ACCOUNT LAST PAYMENT
    ,CALP.LAST_PAYMENT_DATE
    ,CALP.LAST_AMOUNT_PAID
    -- FROM CARD_FCC
    ,NVL(CF.CARD_LIMIT_AMOUNT,0.00) AS CARD_LIMIT_AMOUNT
    ,NVL(CF.AVL_LIMIT_BAL,0.00) AS AVL_LIMIT_BAL
    ,NVL(CF.FCY_BALANCE,0.00) AS FCY_BALANCE
    ,NVL(CF.LCY_BALANCE,0.00) AS LCY_BALANCE
    ,NVL(CF.ACCRUED_INTEREST,0.00) AS ACCRUED_INTEREST
    --,NVL(CF.TOTAL_PENALTY_AMOUNT,0.00) AS TOTAL_PENALTY_AMOUNT
    ,FN_BPC_CREDIT_PENALTY_AMT(card.account_number,INVOICE.INVOICE_DATE) AS TOTAL_PENALTY_AMOUNT
    -- DATA FROM SV_OPERATION FILE
    --,NVL(penalty_amt.TOTAL_PENALTY_AMOUNT,0.00) AS TOTAL_PENALTY_AMOUNT
    -- INVOICE DATA
    ,INVOICE.TOTAL_PAYMENT_AMOUNT
    ,PAYMENT_DUE_DATE
    ,INVOICE.OVERDUE_DAY
    --,INVOICE.TOTAL_OVERDUE_AMOUNT
    --,INVOICE.MIN_AMOUNT_DUE
    --,CAPR.LAST_AMOUNT_PAID actual_payment_amount
    --,(INVOICE.MIN_AMOUNT_DUE - CAPR.LAST_AMOUNT_PAID)
    , CASE WHEN sysdate > INVOICE.GRACE_DATE
            THEN decode(sign(NVL(INVOICE.MIN_AMOUNT_DUE,0) - NVL(CAPR.LAST_AMOUNT_PAID,0)),-1,0,NVL(INVOICE.MIN_AMOUNT_DUE,0) - NVL(CAPR.LAST_AMOUNT_PAID,0)) 
            ELSE 0
            END TOTAL_OVERDUE_AMOUNT
    ,INVOICE.PAYMENT_STATUS_CODE
    ,INVOICE.CLASSIFICATION
    ,to_char(INVOICE.INVOICE_DATE, 'DDMMYYYY') AS INVOICE_DATE
    , null PAYMENT_OPTION
    , null SATT_ACC_NUM
    ,to_char(INVOICE.NEXT_DUE_DATE, 'DDMMYYYY') AS NEXT_PAYMENT_DT
    , OL.amt OVERLIMIT
    , 'USD' CREDIT_ACC_CUR
-- START MAIN QUERY HERE
FROM (
    SELECT ACCOUNT_NUMBER
        ,CUSTOMER_NUMBER
        ,listagg(CARD_NUMBER, ',') WITHIN
    GROUP (
            ORDER BY CARD_NUMBER ASC
            ) AS card_number
        , MIN(to_char(START_DATE, 'DDMMYYYY')) AS START_DATE
        ,listagg(to_char(END_DATE, 'DDMMYYYY') , ',') WITHIN
    GROUP (
            ORDER BY CARD_NUMBER ASC
            ) AS END_DATE
        , MAX(to_char(CARD_EXPIRY_DATE, 'DDMMYYYY')) AS CARD_EXPIRY_DATE --OVER (PARTITION BY ACCOUNT_NUMBER) 
        ,listagg(CREDIT_ACCOUNT_CURRENCY, ',') WITHIN
    GROUP (
            ORDER BY CARD_NUMBER ASC
            ) AS CREDIT_ACCOUNT_CURRENCY
    FROM CARD
    GROUP BY ACCOUNT_NUMBER
        ,CUSTOMER_NUMBER
        --,CARD_EXPIRY_DATE
    ) card -- AGGREGATE CARD LEVEL TO ACCOUNT LEVEL USING LISTAGG FUNCTION GROUP BY ACCOUNT NUMBER AND CUSTOMER NO
LEFT JOIN CUSTOMER
    ON CUSTOMER.customer_no = CARD.CUSTOMER_NUMBER
--- LAST PAYMENT
LEFT JOIN CARD_ACCOUNT_LAST_PAYMENT CALP
    ON CALP.SV_CARD_ACCOUNT = card.account_number
-- FCC ACCOUNTING
LEFT JOIN card_fcc CF
    ON CF.SV_CARD_ACCOUNT = card.account_number
-- REPAYMENT AMOUNT
LEFT JOIN CARD_ACCOUNT_PERIOD_REPAYMENT CAPR
    ON CAPR.SV_CARD_ACCOUNT = card.account_number
LEFT JOIN OVERLIMIT OL
    ON OL.D_ACCOUNT_NUMBER = card.account_number
LEFT JOIN (
    select acc.account_number, 
        acc.ACCOUNT_STATUS , 
        dic.ARTICLE_NAME as ACCOUNT_STATUS_DESC
    from SV_A_ACCOUNTS ACC
        join SV_D_DICTIONARIES dic 
        on acc.ACCOUNT_STATUS = dic.DICTIONARY
    where dic.DIC_CODE = 'ACST'
    ) ACC
    on card.account_number = ACC.ACCOUNT_NUMBER
-- AGGREGATED INVOICE CTE BY ACCOUNT NUMBER
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT account_number
        ,INVOICE_DATE
        , GRACE_DATE
        , MIN_AMOUNT_DUE
        ,LISTAGG(INVOICE.PAYMENT_DUE_DATE , ',') WITHIN
    GROUP (
            ORDER BY CARD_NUMBER ASC
            ) AS PAYMENT_DUE_DATE
        , ADD_MONTHS(INVOICE.INVOICE_DATE,1) AS NEXT_DUE_DATE
        ,LISTAGG(OVERDUE_DAY, ',') WITHIN
    GROUP (
            ORDER BY CARD_NUMBER ASC
            ) AS OVERDUE_DAY
        ,SUM(TOTAL_OVERDUE_AMOUNT) AS TOTAL_OVERDUE_AMOUNT
        ,SUM(TOTAL_PAYMENT_AMOUNT) AS TOTAL_PAYMENT_AMOUNT
        ,LISTAGG(PAYMENT_STATUS_CODE, ',') WITHIN
    GROUP (
            ORDER BY CARD_NUMBER ASC
            ) AS PAYMENT_STATUS_CODE
        ,LISTAGG(CLASSIFICATION, ',') WITHIN
    GROUP (
            ORDER BY CARD_NUMBER ASC
            ) AS CLASSIFICATION
    FROM INVOICE
    GROUP BY account_number
        ,invoice_date
        , GRACE_DATE
        , MIN_AMOUNT_DUE
    ) INVOICE
    ON INVOICE.ACCOUNT_NUMBER = CARD.ACCOUNT_NUMBER
ORDER BY ACCOUNT_NUMBER ASC;
```

I am facing an issue while fetching records from Oracle db. ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row.
Here is my Query. The main purpose of the query is to fetching the records whole the week(example: data from 04-Dec-2023 to 08-Dec-2023)
The code works fine for someday but someday it throwing an error. Any help would be appreciated.

execute data properly

Comment: Please [edit] the question and include a [MRE] by which we mean a **MINIMAL** example of your code that demonstrates the same issues as your actual code and include the `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements for your sample data and the expected output. You are highly unlikely to find someone willing to debug a 3-page long query let alone a 20+ page query and especially not when we cannot run the query because we don't have your tables.

Comment: Your first sub-query can be written as `SELECT SYSDATE AS today, TRUNC(TO_DATE(:AS_DATE,'MM-dd-yyyy'), 'IW') AS FOW, TRUNC(TO_DATE(:AS_DATE,'MM-dd-yyyy'), 'IW') + 6 AS EOW FROM DUAL` if you want to get rid of the language dependent code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have queries like:

```sql
SELECT CASE 
       WHEN DRCR_IND = 'D'
       THEN (LCY_AMOUNT) * - 1
       ELSE abs(LCY_AMOUNT)
       END AS LCY_AMOUNT
      ,ac_no
      ,trn_dt
      ,substr(trn_ref_no, 4, 4) as PRODUCT_CODE
      ,(
         SELECT DISTINCT iss_account_number AS sv_card_account
         FROM (
           SELECT DISTINCT a.trn_ref_no
                 ,b.iss_account_number
           FROM  iftb_fileupd_xmlcr_trn_custom a
                 JOIN iftb_fileupd_xmlcr_custom b
                 ON a.oper_id = b.oper_id
                    AND a.seq_number = b.seq_number
         ) c
         WHERE c.TRN_REF_NO = a.TRN_REF_NO
       ) AS sv_card_account
```

We do not have your tables or understand your business logic but the outer-query expects the sub-query to return a single row. If the sub-query returns multiple rows (if, for example, the customer has two savings card accounts with different account numbers) then you will get the exception:

```
ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row
```

You could:

- Add:

  ```sql
  AND  ROWNUM = 1
  ```

  or, from Oracle 12:

  ```sql
  FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY
  ```

  To the end of the sub-query if you wanted to ignore when there are multiple returned values and only show one of those values.
- Or you could change the select clause to:

  ```sql
  SELECT LISTAGG(DISTINCT iss_account_number, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY iss_account_number)
  ```

  If you wanted to aggregate multiple values into a delimited list.
- Or you can change to `JOIN`ing that correlated query to the main query if there should be multiple rows returned.

You need to evaluate how your business logic should be handled and go through the query looking for all similar situations and the work out how they should each be handled (we cannot fix them for you as the solution depends on the business logic you want to implement in each case and we have no concept of that).

Comment: Thanks for the information. Could you share the sample code that i have provided with rownum?

Comment: In the snippet in the answer, at the end it would be: `WHERE c.TRN_REF_NO = a.TRN_REF_NO AND ROWNUM = 1 ) AS sv_card_account` However, as stated in the final paragraph, **YOU** will need to go through the entire query and check for similar sub-queries and work out how it would be appropriate to fix those too.

Comment: Thanks MT0. Let’s me try. Anyway how about final paragraph? What do you mean on that?

Comment: Exactly what is says, there are more sub-queries in your code than the one that I listed in the answer. You need to work out which of the three approaches I have mentioned may be appropriate in each case to the business logic that you want to achieve and then modify the code in each case based on what your requirements are.